# "Speed" vs "Configured Memory Speed" in dmidecode

Tags: linux, memory, speed, overclocking, memory-management

Does the information below from dmidecode indicate that my memory runs twice as fast (overclocked) as nominal or at half speed? (My WWW searches yielded confusing information corroborating both.) And how to change the setting on Acer Aspire V3-571G with Debian 10?

```
Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0010
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 800 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 11FA057C
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: CT51264BF160BJ.C8F
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
```

Comment: Also the "Configured Memory Speed" apparently tends to be called differently on the Internet, most often "Configured Clock Speed". Perhaps it depends on the version of dmidecode.

Comment: Or is "Configured Memory Speed" supposed to be twice the "Speed" because of Double Data Rate (DDR)?

Comment: It's a poor syntax word choice, I believe the actual meaning is opposite of what the words suggest, that is, 'speed' is a system default setting, seems to vary, and 'configured clock/memory speed' is the speed the system booted at, assuming something like under or overclocking of ram speeds, that is, what you configured them to  be. Or as suggested, due to paired ram sticks, doubling the rate, a situation occurring at boot which the system detects.